# Using Firebase open a different activity if user logged in second time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my project. What I want?? When a new user logged in, he goes through all activities (like Information activity, etc) after login and then to the dashboard. when that user logout from the app and logged in again then directly go to dashboard not need to fill that all information again.

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailLogin, passwordLogin).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Bottom_Navigation_Bar.class));
                        } else {


                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, InformationActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sign In , Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Occurred, while Signing In... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

I am using this code, but it takes both new and old users to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checking:

```
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) { ... }
```

Doesn't help you know if the user signs in for the first time, it only checks if the user is authenticated or not. To know is the user signs in for the first time, please use the following lines of code:

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
        if (isNewUser) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The user is new!"); //Send the user through all activities
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "The user is NOT new!"); //Send the user to the dashboard
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> What does getAdditionalUserInfo() method do?

`task.getResult()` returns an object of type [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult). That being said, we can call the above method on such an object, to return an object of type [AdditionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo). As you can see in the docs, there is a method there called [isNewUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser()) that:

> Returns whether the user is new or existing

Comment: *it does not work for me* doesn't provide enough information so I can help. However, I have edited my question with more information. Please check.

Comment: As I mentioned in my edited answer, [getAdditionalUserInfo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult#getAdditionalUserInfo()) returns an object of type AdditionalUserInfo. So you can use any method that exists in there, isNewUser(), getUsername(),  
getProviderId() or getProfile(). That's it. So it doesn't check anything else. If you need another check, you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: Without seeing your code, unfortunately, I cannot be much of a help. So if you come across an error, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I just rolled back your question to the initial one. Please try to follow the rules of this community and ask another question if something else comes up. In this way, I or other Firebase developers can help you. I'd really appreciate it.